# angularAMD.bootstrap(app) line is throwing an exception in IE10 IE11 browsers but works in Google Chrome

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, requirejs, lazy-loading, angular-amd

I am trying to implement lazy loading with [angularAMD](https://github.com/marcoslin/angularAMD)

[Plunker please click to reproduce in IE browser](http://plnkr.co/edit/zXRuFwoncXZux1TgVUCM?p=preview)

Here is my code. Please help me...

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: "js/scripts",

  // alias libraries paths.  Must set 'angular'
  paths: {
    'angular': '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min',
    'angular-route': '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular-route.min',
    'angularAMD': '//raw.github.com/marcoslin/bower-angularAMD/v0.1.0/angularAMD.min',
    'ngload': '//raw.github.com/marcoslin/bower-angularAMD/v0.1.0/ngload.min',
    'restangular': '//cdn.jsdelivr.net/restangular/latest/restangular.min',
    'underscore': '//cdn.jsdelivr.net/underscorejs/1.5.2/underscore-min'
  },

  // Add angular modules that does not support AMD out of the box, put it in a shim
  shim: {
    'angularAMD': ['angular'],
    'angular-route': ['angular'],
    'restangular': ['angular', 'underscore']
  },

  // kick start application
  deps: ['app']
});
```

Comment: Can you post the exception type and the line of code that is causing the problem?

Comment: The body of your question should contain the text of the exception and the code which is relevant to the question. It is fine to provide links to provide additional context but these links cannot **replace** what should be in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by IE refusing to load JS unless mime type is set correctly.  If you check your IE `Developer Tool` console, you will see error:

```
SEC7112: Script from https://raw.github.com/marcoslin/bower-angularAMD/v0.1.0/angularAMD.min.js was blocked due to mime type mismatch
```

The sample code used is loading JS from `raw.github.com` which return the file as `text/html` instead of `text/javascript`.  The solution is simply to recreate the files locally.  See:

http://plnkr.co/edit/lmLLiOSGRVxmzSWV0Oh4?p=preview